# How to check for divisors within an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have one array of n cells with cell 0 having int 0 and cell 1 with in 2 ect... [0,2,3,4,n...]

My goal is to have the the user select a value(not cell #) in the array, the selected value then becomes a zero ONLY IF both of the following condition below are true:

- The user cannot chose a cell that is already a 0
- The user cannot chose a number that does not a remaining divisor in the array. For example; the user cannot chose 3, 4 or 7 in an array containing [0,0,3,4,0,6,7,8]

Any number that the user selected to be unavailable will have `System.out.println ("Invalid number");`

EDIT: My current problem right now is when I have [0,0,0,4,5,6] I can select 4,5 and 6 and turn it into a zero even though there is no divisor for any of these number.

My try for the code, not fully working:

```
int[] NumBox = new int[StartNum];
           for (int i = 1; i < NumBox.length+1; i++)
            {NumBox[i - 1] = i;}




 if (NumBox[pick-1]!= 0)
       { 
                    boolean hasDivisor = false;

                      for (int k = 1; k < NumBox.length+1; k++) 
                   {

                         if (NumBox[k] == 0) 
                         continue;
                         if (NumBox[pick-1] % NumBox[k] == 0) 
                         {
                           hasDivisor = true;
                           break;
                         }
                   }   


                    if (hasDivisor)
                     {
                      score1 = pick + score1;
                      NumBox[pick-1]=0;
                      }

                     else
                      System.out.println ("Invalid number");
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the formatting, mom !

Comment: Fix my algorithm and code aren't too constructive.  Determine the source of the problem.

Comment: _"The user cannot chose a number that does not a remaining divisor in the array"_ -- what does this mean? I'm guessing that the user is only allowed to choose a number that is divisible by another number remaining in the array, but that's only a guess. Please clarify. Also, what does _"not fully working"_ mean? Are we supposed to also guess where the problems are?

Comment: Not sure what's actually going wrong for you here.  But no matter what it is, this seems like the perfect problem to solve by stepping through your code with a debugger (yes, I know this applies to 90% of the questions that get asked on Stack Overflow) - that would be the best way to see what is in your array at any point, as you choose more and more numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what the problem is with your current code, but I'm guessing that you probably want to change this test:

```
if (NumBox[pick-1] % NumBox[k] == 0)
```

to this:

```
if (NumBox[pick-1] > NumBox[k] && NumBox[pick-1] % NumBox[k] == 0)
```

That way you won't consider a number as its own divisor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. here's an approach.

```
1. Sort the array in ascending order.
2. For a given number/input say "n" at index say "i", 
   if any number before index "i" has number!=0 && n%number ==0, then it is divisible. Else, it is not divisible
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach is this

```
    1. Sort the array in ascending order.
    2. Now when the user selects a number, keep testing 
       the mod value from start until root(N) of that number. 
       If none mods to zero, then it doesn't have any divisors.
```

The first part should be easy, the second part would be something like this pseudocode

```
boolean flag=false;
if(!(pick==0)){ // testing if it is already is not zero
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if(pick%NumBox[i]==0){
        //divisor found
        flag=true;
        break;
    }else if(NumBox[i]>Math.sqrt(pick)){
        //No divisors found
        break;
    }
}

}

if(flag==true){
    pick=0;
}
```